# Warnings when executing tensorflow sample code `mnist_with_summaries.py`

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to execute the examples given by TensorFlow. More specifically, the minist example. When I'm executing
`tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py`, line 163, which is :

```
summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step],
                                      feed_dict=feed_dict(True),
                                      options=run_options,
                                      run_metadata=run_metadata)
```

The warning below comes out:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_tracer.cc:513] Unhandled API Callback for 2 41
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_tracer.cc:513] Unhandled API Callback for 2 41
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_tracer.cc:513] Unhandled API Callback for 2 41
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_tracer.cc:513] Unhandled API Callback for 2 41
```

Any ideas on why this warning happen?
The full code is avaliable at [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py) over which I changed nothing.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning message and should be harmless. A fix is also in progress: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2959